# PHP - Count SQL Results Per Day

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I have a table called `Users`which contains a table structure like this:

Lets say I have a mysql table called 'signups' with the following values:

```
UID|Name|Regdate
1|Admin|2014-03-04 10:51:01
2|Demo|2014-05-04 09:51:05
```

I want to create a graph showing how many people signed up in one day. I used this SQL Query:

```
SELECT DATE(regdate) AS `Date` , COUNT(*) AS Signups FROM `users` GROUP BY DATE(regdate)
```

It gave me an output of:

```
Date|Signups
2014-03-04|1
2014-05-04|1
```

I wanted the output in a PHP File so I made this

```
<?php include_once("inc/db.php"); ?>

<?php 
$query ="
SELECT  DATE(regdate) AS `Date`
    , COUNT(*) AS Signups 
FROM    `users` 
GROUP BY 
    DATE(regdate)
    ";
     $query_params = array( 
    ); 
     try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    echo $result;
    ?>
```

When I try to access the page, the result I get should be same thing I got from the SQL Query. However the result I get is `1`. As you can see, I am using PDO. I am a beginner please help me please. :)

Comment: That's because ->execute returns a bool. If you want the data, you want to use the fetch* methods available from $stmt. Please see [this for usage](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use `mysqli` or `PDO`? Anyway `execute` does not do the job of returning the eventual result, assuming you use `PDO`,  you have to:

```
 try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 

        foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $fetch)
        {
            // do something
        }
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    echo $result;
```

Comment: Yes, I am using PDO. What would I need to do to display the data like this?

    DATE | NUMBER

Comment: Also, I am getting this error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?> ', expecting catch (T_CATCH) in C:\xampp\htdocs\char\jsontest.php on line 22

Comment: well you have probably two `?>` , find the extra one and remove it

Comment: where is your `catch` part of the `try`? This file is not syntactically correct, it should end with a catch following try.

Comment: Hi, I totally forgot about the catch part! Thanks a lot, I was wondering if the json_encode() function would work with this query?

Comment: yes it would work. You may accept the answer if it helps you, for future visitors.